# Document Library WebPart open to specific folder

Tags: 2013, web-part, document-library, folder

Is there a way to have a Document Library WebPart open to a specific folder?

I've been playing around for a few hours and I don't see a decent option.

Comment: Is this just a view of the document library put on a page?

Comment: I could be mistaken there is filter on a view that will show you everything under a folder (as far as I know views are folder agnostic)

Comment: any other thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Adding to jkandiko's answer (which worked for me),

If the URL of the page containing your document list web part is `http://www.mySharePoint.com/SitePages/Home.aspx`, append the text `?RootFolder=((Path to target folder))` to this URL.

The `?RootFolder=((...))` can be found by navigating to the target folder in the document library, then checking the resulting URL.

Comment: This is the least terrible workaround I was able to find for this.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to get document list web parts to open to a specific folder by changing the URL.  If you put RootFolder=PATH, the document library will open to that folder.  The problem is, it does it for all libraries on the page.  But maybe this will get you in the right direction:

RootFolder=/PATH/TO/Shared Documents/FOLDER NAME

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to accomplish something similar.

1. Create a new Document Library for each collection of documents you want to show in unique web parts.
2. Create a web part that points only to this Document Library.

All the files are not in the same Document Library, but you can manage them in one place using the Site Contents view.